# What is the liquifaction pressure for hydrogen?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, pressure, temperature

According to the most reliable source on the internet. Hydrogen has a density of 0.07099 Kg/L. Thus divided by it's molecular mass, in one liter of liquid hydrogen we should have 35.21888395 mol.

Suppose the same liquid hydrogen is kept in that same container without venting. Then allowed to reach standard room temperature 20°C. Using the gas law I get:

P = (35.21888395 * 8.31446261815324 * 293.15) / 0.001 = 85.842 Mpa

Yet other sources suggest that liquid hydrogen can only be distributed under cryogenic conditions. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The P-T diagram at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen will help.

Comment: Hmm, not really. The log scales are hard to pick out.

Comment: Atmospheric pressure is $0.1$ Mpa. $858$ atmospheres is about the pressure at the bottom of the ocean. Specialized submarines have been built to take pressures like that, but it isn't cheap or easy.

Comment: So my math is correct?

Comment: The critical temperature of hydrogen is 33K. You can put that much pressure on, if you like, but it won't turn liquid above that temperature. Don't know where the next critical point to metallic hydrogen is... but certainly nowhere close. The critical pressure at the critical temperature is 13 bar, so you are way overestimating the pressure.

Comment: So it won't liquefy but am I storing the same amount of hydrogen?

Comment: https://www.echemi.com/community/at-what-pressure-will-hydrogen-start-to-liquefy-at-room-temperature_mjart2203314030_152.html#:~:text=The%20pressure%20required%20to%20reach,into%20a%20(supercritical)%20fluid.

Comment: In the phase diagram in Widipedia, $300$K is about halfway between $10^2$ and $10^3$. So $2.5$ on the vertical scale. $900$ Mpa is about $10^9$ Pa, so $9$ on the horizontal scale. A bit below "f" in "molecular fluid". That temperature and pressure are above the critical point where the difference between gas and liquid ends. It is a molecular fluid, so the pressure is not high enough to break molecular bonds.

Comment: Your arithmetic is right. You would have the amount of Hydrogen you calculate. The problems are practical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At one atmosphere of pressure, molecular hydrogen liquefies around 20K and freezes around 14K.

If you allow the pressure to vary, you discover that the liquid-vapor boundary extends from the triple point at  13.8K and 7.0kPa to the critical point at 32.9K and 1.29MPa. Atmospheric pressure is about 0.1MPa = 100kPa.

At temperatures above the critical temperature at 33K, there *is no* phase transition from vapor to liquid. The phase diagram below

[image: phase diagram]([source](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_of_hydrogen.png))

is a little annoying to read because you have to do the log scales yourself.  Room temperature is $\log_{10}300\,\rm K≈2.5$ on the vertical axis, and the triple point is at $\log_{10} 33\,\rm K≈1.5$ and $\log_{10}1.3\,\rm MPa ≈6$. It looks like you could generate solid hydrogen at room temperature and about $10^{10}\,\rm Pa$ pressure, but below that you would have a supercritical fluid.

Comment: I think your answer is closest the the question I actually asked. Though I think I asked the wrong question. :)

Comment: I'm suspicious of that diagram. What happened to 5 on the vertical axis?

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, good eye. Wikipedia is amazing: both great and terrible. I can vouch that the lower-left "gas/liquid/solid" corner is *qualitatively* right, but I don't have a better reference at hand.

Answer (score 0):

86 MPa (860 bar) is a probably too high a pressure to be practically useful for engineering liquid/fluid transport.

Comment: That no longer appears to be the case. These guys are saying 700Bar, but that's with a safety factor of 3.  https://steelheadcomposites.com/

Comment: This seems to be a comment on the engineering relevance of the question, rather than an answer to the question about pressures associated with phase changes.

Comment: It's sort of both. I was trying to understand an engineering practice and assumed I had the physics wrong. It turns out I did, but in a completely different way to what I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Hydrogen can be stored using six different methods and phenomena: (1) high-pressure gas cylinders (up to 800 bar), (2) liquid hydrogen in cryogenic tanks (at 21 K), (3) adsorbed hydrogen on materials with a large specific surface area (at T<100 K), (4) absorbed on interstitial sites in a host metal (at ambient pressure and temperature), (5) chemically bonded in covalent and ionic compounds (at ambient pressure), or (6) through oxidation of reactive metals, e.g. Li, Na, Mg, Al, Zn with water. The most common storage systems are high-pressure gas cylinders with a maximum pressure of 20 MPa (200 bar). New lightweight composite cylinders have been developed which are able to withstand pressures up to 80 MPa (800 bar) and therefore the hydrogen gas can reach a volumetric density of 36 kg.m(-3), approximately half as much as in its liquid state. Liquid hydrogen is stored in cryogenic tanks at 21.2 K and ambient pressure. Due to the low critical temperature of hydrogen (33 K), liquid hydrogen can only be stored in open systems.

*The phase diagram of hydrogen suggests it's not possible to liquify it at 20°C so  whatever the pressure may be it's immaterial. It's obvious to say 'liquid hydrogen can only be distributed under cryogenic conditions' since liquid hydrogen exists only in very low temperature conditions!*

> What am I doing wrong?

You are neglecting basics of thermodynamics.

Nothing of mine!

Source: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8618603_Hydrogen_storage_methods

Comment: @PM2Ring typo .

Comment: In that case though why is the number half? If the same molar quantity expands to a pressure of 85.842 Mpa?